# install_requires in setup.py file of Python package errors

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I am building a Python package and my package has some install requirements. This is my setup.py file code:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="simpleEDA", 
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Muhammad Shahid Sharif",
    author_email="chshahidhamdam@gmail.com",
    description="A wrapper around Pandas to perform Simple EDA with less code.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="github link here",
    packages=['simple_eda'],
    install_requires = ['matplotlib',
'numpy',
'numpydoc',
'pandas',
'scikit-image',
'scikit-learn',
'scipy',
'seaborn'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independen.t",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.5',
)
```

I have created the whl file and uploaded it on test PyPI. here is the link

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ simpleEDA==0.0.1
```

If I try to install it, it gives me this error.

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpydoc (from simpleEDA==0.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpydoc (from simpleEDA==0.0.1)
```

Why is my install_requires is not working? Why it is not installing libraries?

Comment: `numpydoc` requires `Sphinx1.6.5+` [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/numpydoc/)

Comment: So? it should auto install other dependencies

Comment: should I also include sphinx in install_requires?

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from simpleEda==0.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib (from simpleEda==0.0.1)

Comment: now its giving me error in matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to install using TestPyPI as the index:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ simpleEDA==0.0.1
```

However most of your subdependencies don't exist on TestPyPI, for example https://test.pypi.org/project/numpydoc/ is 404.

Depending on what you're using TestPyPI for, you might be better off making a [pre-release](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#pre-release-versioning) on PyPI instead.